# How do i add values from other google sheets together and display them on one sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

So I've created a few google sheets to track the hours I've worked with different clients and I'd like to create a master sheet that displays this as the total hours worked each day. My current sheets are already formatted like calendars with the hours inputed on a daily basis so its really just adding the same "day" across 6 or 7 sheets and displaying them on one.

I've tried the importrange function but every time i get a new client i have to add the new importrange manually to every day's sum for that month. There must be an easier way no?

Currently, I have this:

```
=SUM(IMPORTRANGE("client 1 link", "January!F10"), IMPORTRANGE("client 2 link", "January!F10"), IMPORTRANGE("client 3 link", "January!F10"), IMPORTRANGE("client 4 link", "January!F10"), IMPORTRANGE("client 5 link", "January!F10"))
```

[Example of one of the sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VNBp.jpg)

Comment: Actually I think, the easiest way is to have one sheet  - master sheet with a column named 'client' where you mark which hours you work for this particular client. Then you use only one file. And if you want to sent a sheet for your client to view, you can add a filter sheet that will show only days / hours you worked for them.

Answer (score 1):

### Dynamic ImportRange

This solution will only have 1 tab for each client in the overview workbook.  You select the month you want to summarize, and it will import just that month into each client's tab.

### Setup

Refer to these two sheets:

- [Calendar Overview](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18RzDRuEVCdnFie-MbgID80c1nlkyglgOTkieSh2PCwE/edit?usp=sharing)
- [Individual Client](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vg_qiZLkOvlCInxh5_bEVQxyLCeK8ucYHTHcfKejdUE/edit?usp=sharing)

**Individual Client Workbook**

1. For each month, create a named range for the calendar table.  Example: March tabs named range would be Mar_2021, then April's would be Apr_2021, etc.
2. *Every client needs to have the same named ranges*, this is what you will use to import a specific month into your overview workbook.

**Overview Workbook**

1. In the workbook you will be using to aggregate all of the separate client sheets, add tabs for each client in addition to the overview tab, also add extra tabs so you don't need to update the formulas each time.
2. On the overview tab, Create a dropdown that has the Month_Year named ranges, this will select the month that will be imported into each client's tab. **In this example it is B3.**
3. **In the same cell of each client tab add IMPORTRANGE("Client Workboook URL", B3)**. If you use A1, then place the formula in A1 on all tabs. This will import only the month you selected on the overview tab.
4. Finally, on the overview tab, add your sum formula for the same cell on each tab.  The key here is to have enough extra tabs to accommodate new clients.  You can also change a tabs client as you add / lose clients.

Now you can go to the overview tab, select the month you want to view, and it will update each client's tab with that month, and add them all together on the overview tab.

Comment: Okay so I added the screenshot on the post and im going to try what you just suggested although i'm a bit worried it will make the sheet to big. I could always just make a new sheet for each month though. I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: Updated my answer, it will take a bit of setup, but then should be fairly easy to manage going forward.